# Why does this akka-http route test never complete successfully?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I've a simple route and some tests that success individually, but collectively fail with timeout. Any idea why?

```
val route = (requestHandler: ActorRef @@ Web) => {
   get {
     pathPrefix("apps") {
       pathEndOrSingleSlash {
         completeWith(implicitly[ToEntityMarshaller[List[String]]]) { callback =>
           requestHandler ! GetAppsRequest(callback)
         }
       } ~ path("stats") {
         completeWith(implicitly[ToEntityMarshaller[List[Stats]]]) { callback =>
           requestHandler ! GetStatsRequest(callback)
         }
       }
     } ~ path("apps" / Segment / "stats") { app =>
       completeWith(implicitly[ToEntityMarshaller[Stats]]) { callback =>
         requestHandler ! GetStatsForOneRequest(app, callback)
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

and tests:

```
val testProbe = TestProbe()
val testProbeActor = testProbe.ref
  .taggedWith[Web]

val timeout = 1.minute

"Route" should "respond to get apps request" in {
  implicit val routeTestTimout = RouteTestTimeout(timeout.dilated)
  Get("/apps") ~> route(testProbeActor) ~> check {

    testProbe.receiveOne(timeout) match {
      case GetAppsRequest(callback) => {
        callback(k8SProperties.apps)
      }
    }
    entityAs[List[String]] should contain("test")
  }
  testProbe.expectNoMessage(timeout)
}

it should "respond to get stats request for all apps" in {
  implicit val routeTestTimout = RouteTestTimeout(timeout.dilated)
  val app = "test"
  Get("/apps/stats") ~> route(testProbeActor) ~> check {

    testProbe.receiveOne(timeout) match {
      case GetStatsRequest(callback) => {
        callback(List(Stats(app, ChronoUnit.SECONDS, Nil)))
      }
      case other => fail(s"Unexpected message $other.")
    }
    entityAs[List[Stats]].size shouldBe (1)
    entityAs[List[Stats]].head.app shouldBe (app)
  }
  testProbe.expectNoMessage(timeout)
}

it should "respond to get stats request for one app" in {
  implicit val routeTestTimout = RouteTestTimeout(timeout.dilated)
  val app = "test"
  Get(s"/apps/$app/stats") ~> route(testProbeActor) ~> check {

    testProbe.receiveOne(timeout) match {
      case GetStatsForOneRequest(app, callback) => {
        callback(Stats(app, ChronoUnit.SECONDS, Nil))
      }
      case other => fail(s"Unexpected message $other.")
    }
    entityAs[Stats].app shouldBe (app)
  }
  testProbe.expectNoMessage(timeout)
}
```

**Edit**:
Opened https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/1615

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code, thanks to me.

```
"Routes" should "respond to get apps request" in {
  testProbe.setAutoPilot((_: ActorRef, msg: Any) => {
    msg match {
      case GetAppsRequest(callback) => callback(List("test")); TestActor.KeepRunning
      case _ => TestActor.NoAutoPilot
    }
  })

  Get("/apps") ~> handler ~> check {
    entityAs[List[String]] should contain("test")
  }
}
```

Putting `TestProbe` inside `check` hangs forever probably because it creates a deadlock; test waits for callback to be called, and callback isn't called until the body is executed.

Using autopilot sets up an "expectation" that can be fulfilled later thus avoiding the deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using a single TestProbe across all three tests.  That TestProbe is a single actor and is therefore receiving messages from all three tests.  If you simply move your test probe creation and config inside the test bodies, it should work as you expect; specifically these two lines:

```
val testProbe = TestProbe()
val testProbeActor = testProbe.ref
  .taggedWith[Web]
```

Comment: That thought did cross my mind. I had already tried that and it didn't make any difference. Besides, I'm using `TestProbe` in a similar manner in other tests with `Actor`, no problems so far. Lastly, what do you think is the problem if the `TestProbe`receives multiple messages?

Comment: When you are using a TestProbe you are (a) doing something and (b) checking to see how the TestProbe reacts (receives a message or doesn't, etc).  If you use the same TestProbe in different tests then when you check for a reaction you can't tell if that reaction is to something you did in the current test or in another test.  You can mitigate the problem by ensuring all of your tests run sequentially rather than concurrently.  Given the risks of puzzling results, I'd recommend creating the TestProbe inside of each test unless there is a really compelling reason to share one across tests.

Comment: Not really. The tests use different request responses. If multiple tests use the same request-response, then what you say could be a concern. It is dependent on use case, it's not a rule. I don't see any benefit from copy-pasting the code all over the place, or using a fixture.

Comment: Well almost.  TestProbe is an actor with a message inbox.  Suppose you have Test 1 with distinct response A and Test 2 with distinct response B, each test does some stuff and both call `testProbe.receiveOne(timeout)` (as you do).  You cannot control: (1) which response gets stuffed into the inbox first and (2) which test will hit its `receiveOne` call first.  As a result you cannot control which test will receive A and which will receive B.  You can _filter_ response B out of Test 1 should it receive it but (a) Test 2 will then never get B and (b) Test 1 will never get A (it receives one only)

Comment: I upvoted you, but as I said earlier, `TestSubsriber` is not my problem. The test times out, it doesn't fail weirdly, which is what I'd expect if the `TestSubsriber` were shared.